# Save And Retrieve Data In Multiple Activites Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm new in android, I am developing web application by android studio.

When user open application, there is activity login. User need input ipaddress of server, username and password before access application.

What I want to know, Is it possible to save ippaddress and other data to something like SEASSON/Cookies Web in Android Studio? So user only need 1 time to input data, store it and ALL activity inside application will get that data everytime it needed.

Thankyou my friends.

Comment: You can use basically SharedPreferences to do that. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the User's Login data locally, encrypt the values and store it in Shared Preferences or in SQLite Database.

I think storing it locally is the best option because it wouldn't require your app to make network calls every time user opens the app.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:
1. If you have a web service, encrypt and persist the values securely to your web service via a post
2. Encrypt and store the values in shared preferences
3. Encrypt and store the values in a sqlite data base on the device.